# What is the .NET equivalent of PHP var_dump?

Tags: .net, reflection

I remember seeing a while ago that there is some method in maybe the Reflection namespace that would recursively run `ToString()` on all of an object's properties and format it nicely for display.

Yes, I know everything I could want will be accessible through the debugger, but I'm wondering if anyone knows that command?

Comment: Today use any good serializer

Comment: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myVar)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is/was called ObjectDumper.  It uses reflection to iterate through and output all of the different properties for an object. I first heard about it while learning LINQ, and most of the examples in the Linq in Action book use it.

It appears that Microsoft didn't include it in the final version of Linq though, but the code is still out in the wild.  I did a quick google search for it and here's a link to it:

[ObjectDumper Source Code](http://objectdumper.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Example code to dump an object and its properties can be found here:

http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3713886

Answer (score 3):

You can write it by yourself. For example, serialize it into json using Newtonsoft's JSON.net library and write that json to console. Here is an example:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

static class Pretty
{
    public static void Print<T> (T x)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Pretty.Print(whatever);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

I could certainly see the use in such a thing, but in .Net won't you mostly just get a list of type names (String, Array, etc)?  Most of the built-ins don't have "useful" ToString() overloads pre-written, do they?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link with code dumper and a demo project that shows you how to use it. [Download it here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_syntax/reflection/article.php/c5885).